# Global variable in javascript (declare it from one file, put value from another file and accessing it from some another file)

Tags: javascript

I declared javascript global variable in **global.js** file eg:

```
var glbValue;
```

and putting the value of global variable glbValue from **first.html** eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onBtnSubmit()
{
   glbValue=123;
}
</script>
```

and accessing the global variable glbValue from **second.html** eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onBtnClick()
{
   alert(glbValue);
}
</script>
```

it gives me output **undefined** inplace of 123, why ?

Comment: the browser doesn't know that there is a variable called `gbValue` with value `123` when it loads `second.html`. are you loading `first.html` and then loading `second.html` within `first.html`?

Comment: What are you expecting then? global.js is loaded for both the html files and value gets reset.

Comment: P.S reference to the first page will not be available in the second page. So the value you assigned wont be there in the second page.

Comment: You need to use `cookies` in case you wish to share a variable between pages

Comment: @anurupr yes first i load first.html and onsubmit on it i will navigate to second.html

Comment: so you need to use a form as well as a server side script to process the submitted values or you need to check @R3tep's answer for using local storage.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the local storage :

**first.html** :

```
localStorage.setItem("glbValue", "123");
```

**second.html** :

```
alert(localStorage.getItem("glbValue"));
```

Answer (score 2):

When a page loads, all its script files are executed in a new context. The browser does not '*remember*' what you did in the last page. If you want to share a variable between pages, either you use cookies or, even better, `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

1. Use `localStorage` if you want the value to be preserverd even when you close the browswer.
2. Use `sessionStorage` if you want the value to be preserved only during the current session.

I think that the 2º solution is the best in your case:

**first.html**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onBtnSubmit()
{
   sessionStorage.setItem('gblValue', 123);
}
</script>
```

**second.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onBtnClick()
{
   alert(sessionStorage.getItem('gblValue'));
}
</script>
```

You no longer need that global variable.
The only problem with this solution is that IE8 and below do not support this, but there are good polyfills that use cookies transparently.